# Book where a nanotech suit doubles as a spaceship and the hero is cast out of society

Tags: story-identification, nanotechnology

I remember in the book the hero lives in a world where nano-technology is widely used. He himself comes into possession of a nano-tech suit that plays the role of body armor, and (I think) even a means of space travel.

I know for sure the hero is stripped of all his wealth, and force to live outside the controlled society. This is as close to a death sentence as the legal structure of his world allows.

I remember that those in the slums use banner ads (which are quite literally physical banners) for warmth. He eventually reshapes the slum society and rebuilds his wealth.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's certainly John C Wright's, *[The Golden Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Age_%28novel_series%29)*, which is a trilogy. I think you're actually remembering the second volume, *The Phoenix Exultant*. It contains all of the plot elements you mention above.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. I remember the first book now, don't think I ever finished the trilogy so now I've got three books to read.